# Displaying image using base64 string not showing up Image

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm converting a Memory steam to a byte array and encoding it `ToBase64String`

```
   return Ok(Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray()));
```

On the client side i'm doing the following to display the image

```
    var response = await client.GetAsync(Navigator.BaseUri+ "upload/process");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
    imagesrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", response.Content.ToString());
    StateHasChanged();
    }
```

But the image is not getting displayed, it gives the following error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

Update:
This how the image is set

```
<img src="@imagesrc" width="300px" height="300px" style="border: 1px solid #4f4f50; border-radius: 1px" />
```

Comment: You don't show what you do with imagesrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ReadAsStringAsync()` which serializes the HTTP content to a string as an asynchronous operation.

```cs
var response = await client.GetAsync(Navigator.BaseUri+ "upload/process");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var base64 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    imagesrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes peaking the base64 string with debugger will be enlightening indeed.

Comment: @IbrahimTimimi I have tried `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` but it wont work either, the same issue

Comment: It has started to work after i replaced the client side async code `imagesrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);`  Seems it was getting some thread input , not the data

Comment: @techno I assumed if you use `await` then you will get the content instead of the task. Did you try `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`?

Answer (score 2):

`net::ERR_INVALID_URL` means that your base64 (from `response.Content.ToString()`) is not valid base64.

So the error is in the code you left out. Post the full Controller and Client code. Include parameters and [Attributes].

Comment: The controller is doing a lot of stuff from backend.Like pulling data from azure blob container,that is why stripped that code. I can provide you with the content of the base 64 string in the client side https://justpaste.it/715jt

Comment: It has started to work after i replaced the client side async code `imagesrc = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);`  Seems it was getting some thread input , not the data